# How to call a function on onfocus event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually my question is something different.

I called a function on .focus event of the first element of form in my tiny box like below.

```
        $(".tbox :input:visible:enabled:first").focus(function () {
            tabIndexForm();
         });
```

It is working perfectly but this is replacing my own function called on onfocus event on the first element of form which I have set manually. how to do this. my form is:

```
 <form name="exampleform">
  <input type="text" name="a" onfocus="somefunction();"/>
  <input type="text" name="b"/>
  </form>
```

Now when I open the tiny box the tabIndexForm function calls perfectly but somefunction() is not working because I think the tabIndexForm replaces this function. How to upldate the following code to work both.

```
         $(".tbox :input:visible:enabled:first").focus(function () {
            tabIndexForm();
         });
```

Important: I can not call "somefunction()" in tinybox.js because this is common for all tiny boxes.

Comment: function is right, possibbly you're doing some other things wrong. use dev tools with browsers to see them.

Comment: Make sure your somefunction is accessible and show if possible where you define it

Answer (score 2):

The 'focus' function /binds/ an event handler to the element.

Try the new 'on' function, which /adds/ an event handler.

```
$(".tbox :input:visible:enabled:first").on('focus', function () {
        tabIndexForm();
});
```

**EDIT** first try doesn't work.

That should work better:

```
$(".tbox").on('focus', ":input:visible:enabled:first", function () {
        tabIndexForm();
});
```

That way the event handler is not attached to the element, so it doesn't overwrite the old one.

Comment: This form of `on()` does bind a handler to the event, just like `focus()` does.

Comment: I didn't try it, I was just looking at the documentation and noticed the different wording.

Comment: I want to append tabIndexForm() on onfocus not replace the previous

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var elem = $(".tbox :input:visible:enabled:first");
var oldFunc = elem[0].onfocus;
elem.focus(function () {
    if(typeof oldFunc == 'function') oldFunc.call(elem[0]);
    tabIndexForm();
});
```

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/8JbvY/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `onfocus` property from your element:

```
<form name="exampleform">
  <input type="text" name="a"/>
  <input type="text" name="b"/>
</form>
```

And change your javascript to:

```
$(".tbox input[name='a']").focus(somefunction);

$(".tbox :input:visible:enabled:first").focus(function () {
     tabIndexForm();
});
```

This is also a neater way of dealing with your event handlers as you are keeping the logic in one place.

Comment: actually I cannot add the line $(".tbox input[name='a']").focus(somefunction); in tinybox.js. this is not common ok!

Comment: @ManishJangir Why not? How does this differ from your other event handler?

Comment: for me when I add this, focus is attached directly to the input box on page load, which is not what I want. I want the function to trigger when the input box is focused.